# telnet LINEMODE suboption TRAPSIG does not work

Tags: c++, linux, telnet

I want telnet client to pass interrupts/signals as their normal ASCII values in message to server.

I send following telnet command from server to client in my code.

---

IAC SB LINEMODE TRAPSIG 0 IAC SE

```
sprintf(msg, "%c%c%c%c%c%c%c", 255 /*IAC*/, 250 /*SB*/, 34 /*LINEMODE*/, 
2 /*TRAPSIG*/, 0 /*mask*/, 255 /*IAC*/, 240 /*SE*/);
```

---

But on pressing Ctrl+c on telnet prompt, client still pass telnet commands rather then ASCII values.

Message received by server: **IAC IP** IAC DO 6 (timing mark)

Instead of "IAC IP" I want to receive ctrl+C (3).

Any idea how I can make client to send across ASCII values rather than telnet commands while server receives whole line from telnet client not character by character.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you include `<arpa/telnet.h>` to get all the symbolic names as macros?

Comment: Also, what do you get for reply to the request?

Comment: Thanks Joachim for suggestion. I am getting as reply - IAC IP IAC DO 6 .

Comment: I mean, what reply do you get for the `IAC SB ...` request, not when you press CTRL-C.

Comment: No response for that. The first message I see from client is - IAC IP IAC DO 6.

Comment: It seems that the client you're negotiating with doesn't follow [RFC1116](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1116). Quote: "When the client side of a connection receives a MODE command, it MUST agree with at least the state of the EDIT and TRAPSIG bits." And from my reading of the RFC, it seems to me that the other side of the connection should send a reply with `MODE_ACK` set, but it's not clear if a client must do it.

Comment: Thanks Joachim for replying. That's what I was expecting from reading RFC. But not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your way to negotiate `LINEMODE` is not correct.

You cannot send an `IAC` `SB` out of the blue for an option that hasn't been negotiated first with a `WILL` or `DO` or that hasn't been replied positively with a `DO` or `WILL`, respectively.

For line mode in particular, according to [RFC 1184](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1184), the server side should only ever initiate `IAC` `DO` `LINEMODE` (not a `WILL`).

It would then wait for the client to reply with either `IAC` `WILL` `LINEMODE` or `IAC` `WONT` `LINEMODE`. In the latter case, there's nothing you can do, as the client isn't willing to support line mode at this point in time and subsequently sending a sub-negotiation will be pointless (a conforming client will then just ignore it).

If the client answered your request with `IAC` `WILL` `LINEMODE`, that means further sub-negotiation of line mode will take place, but **it will usually be initiated by the client**, not by you (the server).

That means you should now wait for the client to send send `IAC` `SB` `LINEMODE` something `IAC` `SE` and in reaction to that you should request a `MODE` and a `FORWARDMASK` as suboptions.

In particular, you want to request `EDIT` be turned **on** in the client, as that's the actual mode where the client sends only complete lines, and more importantly you want to request `TRAPSIG` be turned **off** in the client, as trapping the signals means the client intercepts the key presses in question and translates them into Telnet commands (such as `IAC` `IP`), which you **don't want**. That is:

`IAC` `SB` `LINEMODE` `MODE` **1** `IAC` `SE`

*(1 means `EDIT` on and `TRAPSIG` off.)*

And you also want to negotiate a `FORWARDMASK` where all bits associated with the control characters you wish to receive are set, otherwise you will receive those characters only when the client sends the completed line or even not at all.

For Ctrl-C (ASCII 3) the minimum forward mask request would be:

`IAC` `SB` `LINEMODE` `DO` `FORWARDMASK` **16** `IAC` `SE`

*(The 16 is decimal. Note that the bits are counted starting from the **MSB, not the LSB**, which can be confusing if you're not aware of it.)*

Then you will have to wait for the client to acknowledge both the mode as well as the forward mask. The client is required to honor the server's request for the `EDIT` and `TRAPSIG` settings if it previously agreed to negotiate line mode at all (however, this is no guarantee that it will pass the special key presses on to you), but it is free to refuse the forward mask.

In the end, if you want the client to successfully negotiate the desired options with you, you will need to make sure you stick the protocol as close as possible. I suggest you at least read and understand the sample communication in [section 5.10 of the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1184#section-5.10).